# Finding $v(m)$ in $\int_{M_0}^{m} \frac{dm}{mR +\frac{I}{R}} = \int_{0}^{v} \frac{-dv}{uR}$

Tags: integration

I've been trying to understand the mathematical technique that was used in finding the value $v$ while trying to solve a "physics" question. now I know it might be unrelated to this branch in MSE in some way, but I purely wanted to know how mathematically they reached such an answer.

here is the euqation : $$ \int_{M_0}^{m} \frac{dm}{mR +\frac{I}{R}} = \int_{0}^{v} \frac{-dv}{uR} $$

and the answer is $$v(m)=-u\ln \frac{m+\frac{I}{R^2}}{M_0 +\frac{I}{R^2}}$$

while $m=\frac{M_0}{2}$

and final answer is $$ v=u\ln\frac{3}{2} $$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\int_{M_0}^{m} \frac{dm}{m +\frac{I}{R^2}} = \int_{0}^{v} \frac{-dv}{u}\implies \ln(m+I/R^2)\Bigg|_{M_0}^m=-v/(u)\Bigg|_0^v\\\implies \ln\frac{m+I/R^2}{M_o+I/R^2}=-v/(u)$$
So:
$$v=-u\ln\frac{m+I/R^2}{M_o+I/R^2}$$

Comment: I would say $\quad v=-u\ln\frac{m+I/R^2}{M_o+I/R^2}$

Comment: yes, there is an extra $R$ that u multiplied with.